# VS Code Debug can not be run in new version extension C# From v2.10.28

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In vs code, When I updated C# extension to v2.10.28, the debug can not be run.

Message:
Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'coreclr'(extension might have failed to activate)

But when I return to v2.9.20, it can ben run successful.
The last version v2.12.19 is also not work.
Is there any necessary setting changed?

```json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
```

I return to Extension C# v2.9.20, it can ben run successful.
And The last version v2.12.19 is also not work.

Comment: Issues can always be reported to https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp and maybe workarounds are already there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I update VS code to last versin 1.84.2, and it is fixed.

Comment: Then you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update VS Code to last versin 1.84.2, then fixed.

https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6707